# How can I reload the Chrome PDF Viewer in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

After getting close to maxing out on my RAM, PDFs do not show up  anymore on Google Chrome:

[image]

How can I reload the Chrome PDF Viewer in Google Chrome? I don't want to have to restart Chrome.

I tried going to chrome://plugins hoping I could reload the PDF viewer as I typically do for crashed extensions, but the Chrome PDF Viewer is grayed out:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press Shift+Escape (or go to More tools->Task manager in the menu), click Plugin: Chrome PDF Viewer, and click "End process":

[image]

You also need to kill all minehandler corresponding to PDFs you have tried to open:

[image]

All of the PDFs will now turn into frowny face puzzle pieces. Once they do that, reload the page and they should appear.